# Passing a Rails Ruby Variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a variable in my controller @data that is a very long string.  I have a javascript function that needs access to this variable. Should I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data='<%=j @data%>'
})
```

or should I put the string in an html data-attribute and then do something like:

```
<div data-stuff="<%=h @data%>"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var data=$("div").data('stuff')
})
```

If one is preferable, why?

Comment: if the value is not related to an element then don't use it as attribute, use it as a variable as you have done in the first sample

Comment: It isn't it is just unrelated text.  But I was told that the first example would be slower because rails would have to render the javascript each page load and couldn't cache it.  But in the second it still has to render the html each time...should it really make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between your two options, the former is preferred.

But consider using the gon gem: https://github.com/gazay/gon